# Library is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an app using Ionic, Angular, and Firebase.

Today, I don't know what changed, but I'm having a problem each time I try to build by project.

> :app:preDebugBuild FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
>
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2], [16.0.2,16.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2], [16.2.1,16.2.1]], but resolves to 16.2.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I'm guessing this is a gradle problem?

My `platforms/android/build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my `platforms/android/app/build.gradle` file under `dependencies` looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

and finally my `project.properties` file looks like this:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/bemochi-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/bemochi-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-support-google-services/bemochi-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
```

Does anyone know why I might be having this issue? I honestly have no idea and the few resources online that I've tried using didn't help. I'd appreciate any feedback! Thanks!

Comment: using + sign instead of version level with api is very bad approach

Comment: @faiiziiawan i didn't do that, it was set up that way...

Comment: @faiiziiawan do I have to go and find out what each version is and update that in the `project.properties`? or is there an automatic way?

Comment: it i very simple. by this way you will see a warning at the right side of the gradle. just put 0.0.0 as version or any dummy minimum version and android studio will automatically tells you which latest version you should use